# What does shutdown cause -60 and -79 stand for?

Tags: macos, error, shutdown

I have a Macbook Air 11-inch (mid-2011)
1,8 GHz Intel Core i7
4GB 1333 MHz DDR3
Intel HD Graphics 3000 384MB
macOS Sierra (10.12.6)

Yesterday, I checked through Terminal shutdown causes and it said that my MacBook was shutdown at 16:56 with -60 error code:
`kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: -60`

What does that mean? On the internet, I found out that it can be related to disk errors but the disk is working well.

Also,like a week ago my macbook suddenly turned off with -79 error code, can it be also related to this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: See https://georgegarside.com/blog/macos/shutdown-causes/

Comment: Please copy text as text and not images so that we can read it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a list of shutdown causes:

https://georgegarside.com/blog/macos/shutdown-causes/

`-60` is a disk error, as you mentioned:

> Bad master directory block (badMDBErr).

note that this also says:

> Back up your data, erase the disk and reinstall macOS. **If you continue to run the system, data loss may ensue.** Use Time Machine to keep a backup until you are able to erase and restore. A common symptom is being unable to repair with Disk Utility — as such, erasing the disk is required as mentioned.

but also

> This is a very old error, from the days of Carbon. It’s unknown if this is actually relevant in macOS shutdown codes.

`-79` is:

> Incorrect current value coming from battery.

I'd probably back it up to another drive ASAP and then replace it.

Comment: Thanks,but on the other site it says,that symptoms are error with files and disk,but there is everything okay with my file and disk,S.M.A.R.T has verified it,so that means,that everything is okay. The same thing with battery it is working well and no symptoms

Comment: SMART status alone is not enough to say that a drive is healthy. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.#Provided_information
"The S.M.A.R.T. status does not necessarily indicate the drive's past or present reliability. If a drive has already failed catastrophically, the S.M.A.R.T. status may be inaccessible. Alternatively, if a drive has experienced problems in the past, but the sensors no longer detect such problems, the S.M.A.R.T. status may, depending on the manufacturer's programming, suggest that the drive is now healthy."

Comment: also: https://www.newegg.com/insider/how-long-do-hard-drives-and-ssds-last
"According to a 2013 study by Backblaze, consumer HDDs typically last for three to five years."

Comment: Thank you again,my disk didn't have any problems in the past,but anyways,do you know how to check disk's heath then?(btw I have SSD,not HDD)

Comment: Interesting, I forgot they had SSDs in macbook pros that early. Looks like they were an upgrade config. Anyway, have you tried running first aid in Disk Utility? BTW, you may want to ask a new question, since comments aren't for extended discussion :)

Comment: Alright,thank you) No,I didn't try to run first aid,so I need to try?I thought it is bad to do that,when disk don't have any problems