# -79 shutdown code

Tags: macos, battery, shutdown

Like 2 weeks ago my macbook air 11-inch(Mid 2011) (yes,old) suddenly shutdown,but then it started up normal.
The error code was -79,that means "incorrect value coming from battery".
My battery is charing normaly. Cycles are also normal. It also says,that the condition is good. It's also been 2 weeks and no problems (expect -60 error,but i didn`t saw how did it shutdown and [it is also my previous question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/435452/)).

Intel core i7 1,8 ghz

SSD 128GB

4gb DDR3 1333 mhz

Intel HD Graphics 3000 384 mb

MacOS Sierra(10.12.6)

There is a picture,who needs:

[image]

So,can it be one-time problem?Like,there is no sympthomes.

Comment: It *could be* a one time glitch. Or it could be a harbinger of the future. EG there may be a battery replacement in your future. I would keep an eye on the battery health with something like Coconut Battery. You don't say which year/model it is but batteries don't last forever...

Comment: Sorry,it's old Mac,model is 11-inch(Mid 2011)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would keep a safe backup and carry on. Hardware problems rarely get better and if you use this computer as a tool to make money, it’s usually easy to weigh repair cost vs replace cost based on your hourly rate and if you already have a spare ready.

If this isn’t a work machine, you can wait for more data on how often the system shuts itself off and the pattern or frequency will dictate when you take action.

Three shutdowns in a day three weeks ago seems like a loose cable, but you have the perfect command to search back over different time spans and keep track of things. Excellent work on parsing log files